# Net Core couldn't open web app page in localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've created a net core app but for some reason net core server couldnt redirection the port to localhost.

This is `Program.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using myWebApp.Models;
using myWebApp.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options =>
   options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SchoolContext")));

var app = builder.Build();
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
   var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
   try
   {
       // add 10 seconds delay to ensure the db server is up to accept connections
       // this won't be needed in real world application
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
       var context = services.GetRequiredService<SchoolContext>();
       var created = context.Database.EnsureCreated();

   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
       logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred creating the DB.");
   }
}

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
}
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();

        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");

    });


app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

this is my `index.cshtml` which it supposed to be the web server page, but for some reason, I couldn't access it.

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="row mb-auto">
    <p>Student Name is @Model.StudentName</p>
</div>
```

this is my `index.cshtml.cs` which is the page model of `index.cshtml`

```
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace `myWebApp.Pages`;

public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public string StudentName { get; private set; } = "PageModel in C#";
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
        private readonly myWebApp.Data.SchoolContext _context;

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, myWebApp.Data.SchoolContext context)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context= context;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            var s =_context.Students?.Where(d=>d.ID==1).FirstOrDefault();
            this.StudentName = $"{s?.FirstMidName} {s?.LastName}";
        }
    }
```

if anyone could help me, I'd be really grateful.

Comment: Is there any error message thrown in the console?

Comment: No. it is not. The screen show the usual when the server started. I must to mention that I'm using microservices with postgres, net core and adminer. Both of them init well, except net core.

Comment: Can you remove `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);` and see what happens?

Comment: And are you using Docker compose?